# JAssimp - Can't find dependent libraries

Tags: java, netbeans, assimp

I've compiled the [JAssimp library,](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/tree/master/port/jassimp) and I'm trying to use the library in NetBeans with a project.

I'm setting the library path in Netbeans in the 'run' options of the project as such:

`-Djava.library.path=D:\VB2013Projects\jassimpfinal\x64\Debug`

That path is where `jassimp.dll` is located.

However, when I try to run my project, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: D:\VB2013Projects\jassimpfinal\x64\Debug\jassimp.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1929)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1847)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1119)
    at jassimp.Jassimp.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at opengltutorials.Mesh.loadMesh(Mesh.java:131)
    at opengltutorials.Tutorial.init(Tutorial.java:124)
    at opengltutorials.Tutorial.main(Tutorial.java:238)
```

I've checked the dependencies with Dependency Walker, and it shows that

`Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.` for `jassimp.dll`. However, it doesn't show any functions in red, so I think this is just a red herring (I am probably wrong, though).

What's going wrong with this?

Comment: If you may be interested in a 100% jAssimp, you may help [here](https://github.com/elect86/jAssimp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this by putting the appropriate .dll's in the working directory.